# Only two hours later, couldn’t I find my phone

Tags: inversion

I went to an amusement park. I enjoyed it so much. **Only two hours later, when I needed to use my phone,  couldn't I find my it.**

Is this sentence idiomatic? I mean when I was playing in the park, I didn't have to use the phone, so I didn't know when and where I lost it. Only two hours later, I then couldn't find it.

I try to use inversion here.

If it's incorrect, should I use like "Not until", "Only after", or sort of thing?

Comment: The second _my_ should be omitted (_it_ clearly refers to _my phone_). A more natural way to use inversion would be "It was only two hours later, when I needed to use my phone, that I realised I couldn't find it".

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks for pointing it out. The "my" is a typo.

Comment: @KateBunting There's no inversion in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This adverbial phrase does not trigger inversion. So you should not invert.

Compare

> Only now do I understand.

Here the adverb phrase "only now" has a negative sense.  It means "I didn't understand until now".

But "Only two hours later" does not have a negative sense. It means, positively. The function of "only" is very different.  In this phrase it means "two hour is a short time". So this has a positive sense, and inversion of the subject is not possible.

It seems to me that your example isn't using "only two hours later" correct.  You should say something like "But two hours later" or "However, two hours later".  You might sometimes hear "only" used to mean "however", but in your particular example, it is not used that way.

The adverb "But" doesn't trigger inversion.

> ... But two hours later, when I wanted to use my phone, I couldn't find <s>my</s> it.

(There is a possibility of inverstion if you want to make a rhetorical question,  "... when I wanted to use my phone, could I find it?" This is a question inversion, not negative inversion and has the implied answer "no, I could not")

Comment: The book Practical English Usage has an example sentence: **Not until much later did she learn who her real father was.** So can I say **Not until two hours later, when I needed to use my phone, did I realize I couldn't find it.**

Comment: Or can I not use realize, just "... ,  couldn't I find my it."

Comment: Yes "Not until ... did I realize..." is correct.  The "not until" has negative impact

Comment: It would have to be **...could I not find it**, but even that doesn't sound quite right.